# angularjs - show / hide input field conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input

Im making an angular js app for logging workouts.

When I hit the log workout button, a modal will pop up with input fields to log the workout.

What I would like to do is have a dropdown with designated workout types, and have the input fields below change depending on what type of workout I select.

For example:

If I choose "run" from the drop down, i would like these fields to appear:
start time:
end time:
milage:

But if I were to select "weight", I would like these fields to appear instead:
weight:
number of sets:
set 1:
set 2:

You get the idea. How could I do this conditional hide / show input fields based on what workout I choose? Any good resources out there that explains this?

Comment: I would love to see what you've tried. Please post your code or provide us a link to fiddle, plnkr, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be needing ng-show ng-hide for this purpose.

```
<input ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
```

Here is an example fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/EZbfM/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to look into ng-show and ng-hide. After you select your workout type you'll want an ng-show expression on all of the relevant controls that evaluates to true when the selected workout type makes the control applicable.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow